# How many ways are there to distribute a deck of $52$ cards to $4$ players?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a homework problem that me and my friend got confused on. It says:

> "How many ways are there to distribute a deck of $52$ cards to $4$ players?"

The teacher clarified that each player does not have to have $13$ cards each, meaning $1$ player can have $52$ cards and the others have $0$, $2$ players have $26$, $26$, etc.

So my friend said that the answer should be $4^{52}$ because you have $52$ cards, and each card can be chosen by $1$ of the $4$ players. So you have $4$ options for the first card, $4$ options for the second card, $4$ options for the $52$nd card.

On the other hand, I said that the answer should be $C(4, 52)$, in other words, $\frac{55!}{52!3!}$, because you have $4$ players total with $52$ cards to distribute. Since the problem said the ways you can distribute the deck, the cards itself do not matter. So you are solving for the number of ways you can have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 52$ (with $x_1$ to $x_4$ being each player).

I really don't know which method is correct. Both methods make sense to me but clearly there can only be 1 correct answer.

Comment: Google "stars and bars".

Comment: I understand what stars and bars mean. That is my method, which is 55!/(52! * 3!). I just don't know how to interpret the problem correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you have interpreted it correctly and $n+k-1\choose k-1$ is the correct formula when $0$ is a possibility.

Comment: Ok, but why is my friend wrong? Doesn't it also make sense to count the number of ways for each player to choose each card from the deck? So you have 4^52 that way.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your friend is over counting by quite a lot.  For example their method ignores the order the cards are dealt.  If you are dealt the same set of cards, it does not matter the order.

Comment: @JohnDouma The cards are distinct.  What matters here is which person receives which card, not how many cards each person receives.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see that now. I upvoted your answer, by the way. You are correct. Long and I ignored the fact that we weren't placing cookies in a jar. The cards are different and that makes a difference. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friends method and the Stars and Bars method have one fatal difference between them.

The Stars and Bars method doesn't care which cards goes to whom; only the number of cards each player has is what distinguishes the different possibilities. Think of it as having $52$ cards but they are all blank.

Your friends method is actually correct in this case. What we want is the number of ways to distribute $52$ **different** cards between four people. For example, let player 1 have $51$ cards and player 2 have the last card while players 3 and 4 don't get any cards. Stars and bars would only count this outcome once, but that isn't correct. Maybe player 2 has the Ace of Spades, or the King of Clubs, or the $9$ of diamonds, etc. We need to consider these different outcomes when figuring out the total number of outcomes, which is $4^{52}$

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain their reasoning behind it?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  The cards are distinct, so it matters which person receives which card, not how many cards each person receives.

Comment: Doesn't my answer explain that in the second full paragraph? I never suggested that stars and bars was supposed to be the correct method, unless my answer wasn't clear enough? Would just like to know for future reference. Thank you for the constructive criticism :)

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that the OP's friend is over counting.  The OP's friend is correct, as you can verify by listing all the ways that the four aces in the deck can be distributed to two people.

Comment: I see. Let me edit my answer. Appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: Shouldn't the different cards not matter though? Say you have a group of 4 people and P1 gets all the cards, but the rest get none. Now on the second redraw, P2 gets all the cards. Wouldn't both be the same as drawing all 52 cards to 1 player? Therefore, that must count as 1 way. My friend's method says that is 2 ways.

Comment: The players are taken to be distinct, hence why it said "4 players" rather than something like "4 indistinguishable people", so your friend is still correct. This new method you are referencing would be a different question, and could be tackled by looking at [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is correct.  What matters here is who receives which card.

There are four possible recipients for each of the $52$ cards, so there are $4^{52}$ ways to distribute the cards to four people without restriction.

What you counted is the number of ways of distributing $52$ identical index cards to four people.  If the cards are indistinguishable, what matters is how many cards each person receives.  If we let $x_i$ be the number of cards received by the $i$th person, then the number of ways of distributing $52$ indistinguishable index cards is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 52$$
in the nonnegative integers.  As you seem to be aware, this is equal to the number of ways of inserting three addition signs in a row of $52$ ones, which can be done in 
$$\binom{52 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{55}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the $55$ positions required for $52$ ones and three addition signs will be filled with addition signs.